# Python Error : list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Tags: python, dictionary

I tried to remove duplicates of a list using `set` method and add that value with a key to an empty python dictionary.

But it gives me that error message

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

I tried this way:

```
mydir =[]
person_trackID = "p7"
class_ids = [3 ,3 ,3 ]
print(mydir,person_trackID,set(class_ids))
mydir[person_trackID] = list(set(class_ids))
print(mydir)
```

please help me to solve this.Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are declaring a list here `mydir = []`

Change it to dictionary `mydir = {}`

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to insert an item into `mydir` at index `'p7'`(which is a string). **Indices are integers and not strings**. That is why the error.

Your question says that you want to insert into a `dictionary` and your code uses a `list`.

> `mydir = {}` - This is a dictionary

> `mydir = []` - This is a list

Here is what you need to do:

```
mydir = {}
person_trackID = "p7"
class_ids = [3 ,3 ,3 ]
print(mydir,person_trackID,set(class_ids))

mydir[person_trackID] = list(set(class_ids))
print(mydir)
```

```
{} p7 {3}
{'p7': [3]}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are doing great with one little mistake. you are declaring 'mydir' as a python list and giving it 'p7' as an index. Python list can't have string indexes. you can change the first line to following.

```
mydir = {}
```